# Getting syntax errors in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm working on my first big Verilog project and having some problems. Mostly in this snippet:

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin 
    if (ii) begin 
       instruction_register <= bus;
    end
end
for (integer i=0; i<=3; i++) begin 
    assign bus[i] = io ? instruction_register[i] : 1'bz;
end
////////STEP COUNTER////////////
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    step_counter <= step_counter+1;
    if (step_counter == 4) begin
        step_counter=0;
    end 
end
```

I keep getting syntax errors, invalid module item errors, and invalid module instantiation errors and I'm really not sure how to fix them.

the full code can be found at https://github.com/adarmaori/SUP-1-computer/blob/main/control.v

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you have an issue with `for` loop. It is a part of `generate` feature and requires use of `genvar`:

```
for (genvar i=0; i<=3; i++) begin 
    assign bus[i] = io ? instruction_register[i] : 1'bz;
end
```

The rest of issues are related to the code which you have not shown.  You are missing a bunch of semicolons and some var declarations.

Comment: Note that it's highly recommended to have all the generate block labeled (some tools won't compile generate blocks w/o identifiers).  

  
`for (genvar i=0; i<=3; i++) begin : GENERATE_BLOCK_LABEL  
    assign bus[i] = io ? instruction_register[i] : 1'bz;  
end  `